# Problem with EditText centered content, Softkeyboard covering it if there is some gravity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I've this problem with EditText inside a LinearLayout that if I give `android:gravity="center"` or `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` to the EditText, the softkeyboard covers the EditText while typing. When I 1st touch the edittext it works fine, but as I start typing the EditText goes behind the keyboard.

This problem never appears if I don't provide any gravity. But I want the contents to be centered.

Here is the code

```
        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phoneET"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_bet_phn_edittxt"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="10" />
```

I have tried different windowSoftInputMode options(`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan")` in the manifest, but not getting the required result.

Also tried it by removing the `android:textAlignment="center"` or only keeping it and removing gravity. But unsuccessful, please help.

The whole layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_mobile"
android:gravity="center|top"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include layout="@layout/content_header" />


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_phn_view"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
        android:text="Enter phone number"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="@dimen/enter_phn_text_size" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phoneET"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_bet_phn_edittxt"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="10" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: have you tried `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`?

Comment: @AbidKhan yes I have, that brings different problems for me. It also brings all the buttons from the bottom to up.

Comment: Definitely it will bring the other things up if your EditText is in the middle or below then the softKeyboard needs space to be shown.

Comment: try this `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"` so when your screen shown at first the softkeyboard will be hidden and after taping on EidtText it will be shown

Comment: @AbidKhan no no, I just want to bring the edittext up, nothing else. how to do so?

Comment: post your whole layout code

Comment: @AbidKhan the whole view here is a view from ViewPager. Buttons and tabindicator are also there in the main layout.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188822/discussion-between-abid-khan-and-ppb).